# What type of FB app do I need to create for use with my windows 8 JS app?

Tags: javascript, windows, facebook, microsoft-metro

I've had a search around here and either

1. The answer isn't here; or
2. The search engine on here sucks

but,

I am trying to add FB integration to my Windows 8 Metro (yeah I said it) JavaScript app. the only problem is I cant work out what type of app I need to create on Facebook. There are only 3 options, iOs, android, and Web App. If I choose Web App, it asks for a mobile web URL, and of course the app isn't on the web so I assume this will be a problem. Further to this is he fact that the code I need to include in my "mobile app" asks me to define a channelUrl (again, no URL, as its a metro app) so I am very confused.

Anyone here gotten this successfully working and provide me a hint as to which type of FB app I need to create so that I can get the ball rolling?

Answer (score 1):

Choose the first option `Website with Facebook Login`.  In Site `Url`, you should be able to put down whatever you want, eg your own site, blog, etc.

You will use Web authentication broker.  See
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Comment: Cool, thanks!ok, so I will be using the broker to sign in, after that should the tutorials on the facebook page for publishing posts etc work as they normal without any modification?